# how to indicate that a namespace is only for library use?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm working in a project where I happened to define a global `std::map` variable which will store run-time fabricated values. I want to specify that such variable and the two functions (one that updates and other which searches) for that map are only for library use. What I'm doing until now is to declare the `namespace` as `namespace stored__` so that it groups the features which will accomplish the same function. I don't know if there is a standard for such purpose, I'm using `__` at the end to imply that it mustn't be used in to a derived project just the library.

How should I indicate that a namespace is only for library use?

I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: One convention is to use a `details` namespace.  Generally it is understood that the code in there is only for the implementation.

Comment: @NathanOliver thank you so much!

Comment: Note that identifiers that contain consecutive underscores are reserved for the language implementation's use. Basically, the language designers had the same problem as you have now and decided to appropriate all names containing double underscore (among others) to indicate implementation details. Ironically your proposed solution to your problem violates the language's own solution to the same problem. See [reserved identifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I'm doing until now is to declare the namespace as namespace `stored__`

This is a bad idea because that name is reserved to the language implementation.

If you only need to access the names in single translation unit, then you can declare them in an anonymous namespace which will prevent the names from being referred from other translation units.

If that limitation is not possible, then a conventional solution is to use a `details` namespace within the public namespace of the library.

Comment: Aren't only names that **start** with **__** reserved for language implementation?

Comment: @H-005 - In C. C++ reserves more

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Oh, yeah, my bad... "the identifiers with a double underscore **anywhere** are reserved"